# Cannot install applications: error code -60008

Tags: macos, install, error

I am trying to install new applications, but I keep getting this error message from the "Copy" application:

> The operation can’t be completed because an unexpected error occurred
>   (error code -60008).

The applications I am trying to install are:

- git from git-2.2.1-intel-universal-mavericks.dmg
- SourceTree from SourceTree_2.0.5.2.dmg

The message is given after I drag the application on the destination directory, and after being asked if I want it to replace the old one.

In the past I had no problems with them.

Comment: For SourceTree try Check for Updates... in its menu

Comment: @Mark - I cannot do it any longer. SourceTree got corrupted trying to install the new version...

Comment: Googling goves thios http://lists.apple.com/archives/Installer-dev/2008/Mar/msg00022.html - so I think you need to delete all of SourceTree and that might include ~/Library/Application Support/SourceTree - Also Sourcetree includes git (/Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/git_local/bin/git) so you don't need the separate install unless you want command line - And which of the 2 installs you have gives the error?

Answer (score 1):

After many attempts, the only way I could install these applications has been through a manual copy from the command line:

```
sudo hdiutil attach ./SourceTree_2.0.5.2.dmg
sudo cp -r /Volumes/SourceTree/SourceTree.app /Applications/
```

Comment: even after deleting /Application/SourceTree.app ?

Comment: @Mark - Yes. I found no other way...